# Two foreign keys in one table sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

I have 3 tables.

Problem with third table shop_order(maybe not)

When I start python script to create table I have the error:
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "cart_id": syntax error

I tried delete field cart_id or customer_id it works. But with two foreign keys it doesnot work

```
CREATE TABLE account
(
    id integer primary key
);

CREATE TABLE shop_cart
(
    id integer primary key,
    
    FOREIGN KEY (owner_id) REFERENCES account (id)
);

CREATE TABLE shop_order
(
    id integer primary key,
    

    customer_id integer,
    FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES account (id),

    cart_id integer,
    FOREIGN KEY (cart_id) REFERENCES shop_cart (id)

);
```

Comment: On a side note: There is a typo in shop_cart; you call the column `id` in one place and `owner_id` in another.

Comment: I deleted owner_id and other fields to more comfortable read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foreign keys come after the column definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE shop_order
(
  id integer primary key,
  customer_id integer,
  cart_id integer,
  FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES account (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (cart_id) REFERENCES shop_cart (id)
);
```

You should, however, reconsider your table design:

- What is the table shop_cart good for?
- What would it mean if shop_order has a customer_id #1 and a cart_id related to customer #2?
- Why do you call it account in one table and customer in another? Stay consistent.